# How can I extract randomly generated id values?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

https://www.spinxo.com/

I'm trying to extract randomly generated ID values from that site.
But even if I combine those `find_element` options, I can't extract those ID values.
What option should I use to extract it?

```
<ul class="clear list01"><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">2cutecher</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Aceog</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Bushba</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Catcheman</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Contencewo</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Cozyfoot</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Desigoesi</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">FlashTa</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Gamyopra</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Grimazon</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Idolin</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Inetenli</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Jiggyny</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Kenjill</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">LuvFlirty</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Metabre</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">MuraPira</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Patepoi</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Penhama</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">PlusAnguris</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Rawcsto</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Runen</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">SarenApril</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Sexylo</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Slashoest</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">ToughDressy</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Tricar</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Upforia</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Uppertska</a></li><li><a href="#" name="lnkName">Wowro</a></li></ul>
```

[image]

```
driver.get('https://www.spinxo.com/')

spin_btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'spin')
spin_btn.click()

id_list = (driver.find_elements(By.NAME, 'lnkName'))

for id in range(len(id_list)):
    print(id_list[id].text)
```

Comment: You should post the HTML codes in your question, instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

**Two things:**

1. You need to get rid of Consent cookies pop-up before clicking on <kbd>Spin</kbd> button
2. Use Selenium's [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) to effectively wait for the elements to be located by selenium

**Refer the code below:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.spinxo.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Below line will click on Consent button - Use this line if you get the Consent pop-up
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[text()='Consent']").click()

spin_btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'spin')
spin_btn.click()

id_list = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, 'lnkName')

for id in id_list:
    print(id.text)
```

**Console output:**

```
2freethay
BabyZero
BagoYounger
Bellit
BraceLasting
CheerupSuru
CountryBlacken
Eirenga
Entelle
Heerer
Inedcity
Jungshoo
Katia
MelConfident
Mixedia
NumAmerica
Offshowan
Presbusi
PressMissing
Prodigyro
Selfcher
Skribitne
StroonsSunny
Strozvige
Tanyco
Tendreach
Tioniary
VamBe
WardZin
Xyloftwa

Process finished with exit code 0
```